# rest_framework TypeError e.indexOf is not a function | bootstrap.min.css 404 not found

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-rest-framework, typeerror

I'm new to django, I follow a tutorial from udemy (tweetme)
While setting-up rest_framework to load serialized data as json, I get these errors :

> TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
>   in :  jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:82466

and :

> Source map error: request failed with status 404
>   Resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static-directory/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map

I just used serialized classes and simple view to display my data, (I got the display but still have the error)

The output in my console:

> [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5324
>
> [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>   [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>   [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>
> .
>
> //other .css and .js with a success GET (200 and 3xx)
>
> .
>
> [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 121200
>
> [17/Jun/2018 08:50:24] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/img/grid.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1458
>   [17/Jun/2018 08:50:25] "GET /static-directory/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1764

Here is my code:

## in "/tweets/models.py":

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Tweet(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default = 1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content     = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    boolean     = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

## in "/tweets/api/views.py":

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import TweetSerializer
from tweets.models import Tweet

class TweetListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = TweetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tweet.objects.all()
```

## in "/tweets/api/serializers.py":

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from tweets.models import Tweet

class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model   = Tweet
        fields  = [
        "user",
        "content",
        "boolean",
        "timestamp"
        ]
```

## in "/tweets/api/settings.py":

```
STATIC_URL = '/static-directory/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static-storage"),
]
```

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static-serve")

**N.B:** I have no js code I said that I used the code above which uses js from the framework "rest_framework" of django (The framework uses jquery library)
(sorry for the wrong answer, I was on my mobile)

**Is it a framework issue?**

I started a new (clean) django project and did the startup tutorial for 
**django rest framework** in : 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org

by adding this in my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

# Serializers define the API representation.
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

I thank you for your answers

Comment: That is clearly a JavaScript error, so don't you think you should post your JavaScript code?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors, include the error as text instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed the TypeError:**
after figuring out that it was a compatibility problem, I tried to install djangorestframework 3.7.4 which is the first version supporting Django 2.0
(the versions 3.7.5, 3.7.6 and 3.7.7 are also compatible)
**N.B:** I was using djangorestframework 3.8.2

**Fixed the missing bootstrap.min.css 404 not found:**
 I had this on my html :

```
<script src="{% static '/script/ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

the correction was to change the link to :

```
<script src="{% static 'script/ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

I thank you all for your support